# How is form action constructed in jsf?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-1.2

I am a bit new to JSF . I am currently using this [tutorial](http://www.sitenol.com/first-sample-hello-world-example-in-jsf) for my learning purposes . As per the example, everything is working perfectly.

I have a jsp like this :

```
<f:view>

        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

                <h:outputText>Your Good Name :</h:outputText>

                <h:inputText

                    value="#{helloWorldJSFManagedBean.userFormView.userName}"></h:inputText>

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGroup style="text-align:center;">

                <h:commandButton value="Show Welcome Note" type="submit"

                    action="welcomePage"></h:commandButton>

            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:form>

</f:view>
```

When this gets converted in to HTML form,  the form code in chrome bug looks like this :

```
<form id="j_id_jsp_589276466_1" name="j_id_jsp_589276466_1" method="post" action="/HelloWorldJSF/userForm.faces" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
</form>
```

What I am not understanding is : **how is the action string getting constructed ?** I have not provided any action form in the jsp. The only action I provided was the action string in `commandButton` which serves as `from-outcome` .

Comment: Huh? What exactly is your concrete problem with that? Seems obvious that the JSF renderer associated with the component is doing that. If you're curious to the source code, it might be good to know that JSF impls are open source.

Comment: @BalusC : That's the question . How it is happening ? Which renderer is that ? Before I write some code, how can I know what will be the form action ? Depending on that, only the servlet mapping can be done . This may be a very obvious and bssic question for you. But , since I am just learning the ropes in JSF, they are not so for me.

Comment: `FormRenderer`. It's just the current URL (postback). I think it's better to grab a JSF book so that you don't need to post this kind of vague questions.